# wait for an event regulary

Tags: multithreading, events

In a program I need to wait for an event (keypress) and get it's char. after that program will continue. this progress will Repeat several time. in my first try, codes run and any character did not save. I find out I should use threading but I am not Familiar with it. 
can any one give me a simple example.
my first try code

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("a");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("b");
```

and in key press event

```
MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar);
```

that result is just a messagebox "a".
I think program should wait after

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("a");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you asked is unclear. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it I use threading and producer/consumer problem.
after an event it will wait until event method run.